# add objects to array without overwriting

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have my current code

```
let array = {};
          array[date] = [
            {
              Name: Name,
              Cell: Cell,
              Age: Age,
              userId: userId,
              Time: time,
              Type: type,
              read: false,
            },
          ];
```

that uploads to firebase like this
[image]

but every time i add a new entry for the same date, it overwrites the existing data. I want the data to be add to map "1" etc instead of overwriting the data in map "0"

update: I have tried the following and I am receiving an error. Not sure if I did this correctly, I am still learning.

```
 let array = {};
          array[date] = [];
          try {
            await firebase
              .firestore()
              .collection("Notifications")
              .doc(`${helper}`)
              .update(
                {
                  array: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                    Name: Name,
                    Cell: Cell,
                    Age: Age,
                    userId: userId,
                    Time: time,
                    Type: type,
                    read: false,
                  }),
                },

                { merge: true }
              );
          } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
            console.log(e);
          }
```

update with push:

```
 // at beginning of script
          let array = {};

          // later, when you want to add to it
          if (!array[date]) {
            array[date] = [];
          }
          array[date].push({
            Name: Name,
            Cell: Cell,
            Age: Age,
            userId: userId,
            Time: time,
            Type: type,
            read: false,
          });

    

          try {
            await firebase
              .firestore()
              .collection("Notifications")
              .doc(`${helper}`)
              .set(
                array,

                { merge: true }
              );
          } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
```

Solution:

```
try {
  await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("Notifications")
    .doc(`${helper}`)
    .update({
      [date]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
        Name: Name,
        Cell: Cell,
        Age: Age,
        userId: userId,
        Time: time,
        Type: type,
        read: false,
      }),
    });
} catch (e) {
  alert(e);
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Can you please  share your code that is not working as intended?

Comment: That's an object, not an array.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have updated the question

Comment: Remove the `{merge: true}`... It can be used only when you are using `set()`

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have tried both with merge true and set, and with merge with update, i have updated the question again so you can see the other method as well

Comment: Use the first one but either change `update` to `set` or remove `{merge: true}` from update

Comment: that did it! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you set the entire `2022-01-03` field, you are overwriting any existing values in that field.

If you want to merge the new value/object you specify with the existing values in a field [use the `array-union` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have updated the original question with my attempt and your solution. I am receiving an error

Comment: The array union did the trick once i figured it out, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Use `push()` to add to an array.

```
// at beginning of script
let array = {};

// later, when you want to add to it
if (!array[date]) {
  array[date] = [];
}
array[date].push({
  Name: Name,
  Cell: Cell,
  Age: Age,
  userId: userId,
  Time: time,
  Type: type,
  read: false,
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried your solution and it is still overwriting the data

Comment: You should only have `let array = {}` once, at the beginning of the script. The other parts are done every time you want to add something.

Comment: I have updated the original question with your solution, if you could review please. it is still overwriting the data. Did i do it correctly?

Comment: I don't know firebase, so I can't help you with that part. But whenever you say you get an error, you need to post the exact error message.